# Do logged in users need to browse a site over https?

Tags: web-development, websites, https

I've never thought it was necessary, but a client has requested that all webpages served to logged in users be delivered over HTTPS.

Aside from the implementation standpoint, which I don't think I'm going to pursue is there any real reason for this request ?

For clarity, the login / logout process, account settings, registration preferences and all user related scripts are served over https. but I can't see the point in my news articles, press releases, events etc... being served in this manner? Am I missing something ?

Comment: FYI - This question would probably get a better answer out of Security SE.

Comment: If someone wants to move it that's fine by me, or should I just delete it and ask again over there ?

Comment: Good question - depends on the admins here.  It would probably be quicker to ask again there.

Comment: its been answered, if someone wants to migrate it after the fact they can. :)

Comment: Ever heard of session hijacking ?

Comment: Actually, this has already been asked (and answered) on Security SE: [Can a session be hijacked if the user is redirected from HTTPS to HTTP after login?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/can-a-session-be-hijacked-if-the-user-is-redirected-from-https-to-http-after-log)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is basic security. Since HTTP is stateless, even if a user is logged in, the browser still needs to effectively re-authenticate for every single page load (otherwise the server has no way of knowing that this particular user is logged in).

The usual ways to do this are via a special cookie, or by including some token in each rendered page (e.g. as a parameter of all links).

No matter how it's implemented, the key point is: *Every time the browser requests a page it will have to send some secret session key or similar*.

So unless you serve everything over HTTPS, the session of a logged-in user can be hijacked through a man-in-the-middle attack.

---

More information on Security SE: [Can a session be hijacked if the user is redirected from HTTPS to HTTP after login?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14246/can-a-session-be-hijacked-if-the-user-is-redirected-from-https-to-http-after-log)

Comment: Thanks for detailing the attack type I need to be mitigating against, google here I come :)

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS secures the communication channel against eavesdropping: that is, any man-in-the-middle who could otherwise read your traffic without either side noticing will now see nothing but encrypted data, and the encryption is done in a way that it can only be undone either by getting at the server's private key, or by attacking the encryption algorithm itself. Additionally, HTTPS makes sure that the server you're talking to is actually the correct one: the certificate specifically points to a domain name (e.g. `acme.com`), and the server authenticates itself through the certificate; this way, when someone hijacks your DNS and points `acme.com` to their own server, they won't have a valid certificate to serve, and the authentication will fail (this is what happens when your browser throws a huge warning sign in your face).

Now, when you log into a website, the server has to know who you are on subsequent requests, and the way this is usually (well, practically always) done is through a *session cookie*. This cookie is set once at login, and then sent back to the server on every request. Now consider what happens when such a request is not encrypted: an eavesdropper can read it, including the `Cookie` header, extract the cookie, and take over your login. You don't want that.

Technically speaking, only sensitive requests have to contain the cookie and run over a secure connection, but mixing secure and non-secure requests within one document leads to a whole cornucopia of other issues, and it's just too difficult to get right that the general consensus is that it's better (easier and more reliable) to just serve *everything* over HTTPS, including scripts, images, stylesheets, AJAX requests, and anything else you can think of.

Another thing to keep in mind: The Cookie RFC specifies two flags you can set on a cookie: `SECURE` and `HTTP_ONLY`. For session cookies, you should always set both, and here's why:

- `SECURE` instructs the browser to never send the cookie over an insecure connection. When you set it, an attacker won't be able to trick the browser into sending it over an untrusted (and potentially hijacked) connection, which removes an entire class of attack angles from the scene. Similarly, if you missed a spot and your application accidentally sends plain HTTP requests from an HTTPS context, an eavesdropper might still see the cookie without this flag, but with it, the browser will simply silently exclude the cookie from the request. Not all browsers honor this flag, so you still need all the other precautions, but the recent mainstream ones all do.
- `HTTP_ONLY` means the cookie is not accessible from within JavaScript, not even read-only. This prevents combinations of XSS and Session Hijacking attacks, where an attacker uses XSS to plant JavaScript which then reads the session cookie and sends it back home. With the `HTTP_ONLY` flag, the cookie will be invisible to the JavaScript, so the attack won't work.